# Angular - Push service array with itself

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a service to display a list iterating through an array. I want that list to be infinite (on scrolling). Hence my approach was to push the displayed array with itself on scroll.

This worked, but since I've decided to go with services, I can't make it function again.

Service:

```
import { Case } from './case';

export const CASES: Case[] = [
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'WeWork Berlin', image: '/assets/images/berlin.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Fritzhansen', image: '/assets/images/fritzhansen.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Savum', image: '/assets/images/savum.png', image2: '/assets/images/savum/savum-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/savum/savum-iphone.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Eskay', image: '/assets/images/eskay.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel-snd.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Mobilia', image: '/assets/images/mobilia.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Rarekind', image: '/assets/images/rarekind.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' }
];
```

To iterate through this array, I fetched it inside of the case-list component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CASES } from '../mock/mock-cases';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-case-list',
  templateUrl: './case-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./case-list.component.scss']
})
export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {

  cases = CASES;

  ...
```

**How can I push `cases` again, so that it contains multiple `CASES` arrays?**

I've tried: `this.cases.push(CASES)`, but this one won't work.

I want cases to look like this (`CASES` x3):

```
{ name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'WeWork Berlin', image: '/assets/images/berlin.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Fritzhansen', image: '/assets/images/fritzhansen.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Savum', image: '/assets/images/savum.png', image2: '/assets/images/savum/savum-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/savum/savum-iphone.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Eskay', image: '/assets/images/eskay.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel-snd.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Mobilia', image: '/assets/images/mobilia.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Rarekind', image: '/assets/images/rarekind.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },

{ name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'WeWork Berlin', image: '/assets/images/berlin.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Fritzhansen', image: '/assets/images/fritzhansen.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Savum', image: '/assets/images/savum.png', image2: '/assets/images/savum/savum-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/savum/savum-iphone.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Eskay', image: '/assets/images/eskay.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel-snd.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Mobilia', image: '/assets/images/mobilia.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Rarekind', image: '/assets/images/rarekind.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },

{ name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'WeWork Berlin', image: '/assets/images/berlin.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Fritzhansen', image: '/assets/images/fritzhansen.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Savum', image: '/assets/images/savum.png', image2: '/assets/images/savum/savum-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/savum/savum-iphone.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Eskay', image: '/assets/images/eskay.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel-snd.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Mobilia', image: '/assets/images/mobilia.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' },
  { name: 'Rarekind', image: '/assets/images/rarekind.png', image2: '', image3: '', link: '' }
```

Comment: examples are very hard to read. consider making a simplified version of the examples

Comment: @gatsbyz it's just the standard `CASES` service, multiplied by 3 - as mentioned

Comment: Have you tried this? this.cases.push(...CASES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `this.cases.push(...CASES)`. It's called the spread syntax.

For function calls:

```
myFunction(...iterableObj);
For
```

array literals or strings:

```
[...ite`rableObj, '4', 'five', 6];
```

For object literals (new in ECMAScript 2018):

```
let objClone = { ...obj };
```

Comment: This one seems to work, but it instantly adds thousands of entries on scroll to the array which causes the browser to freeze.

Comment: @Tim Where do you add on to the array? ngOnInit?

Comment: To create infinite scrolling with the repeating list I push the array on `(scroll)` - I think that might be the problem, any bypass?

I did this before, but by solely pushing a usual array - didn't cause any issues.

Comment: Is there a way to add `CASES` in a more "controlled" way?

Comment: @Tim Can you add `if (cases.length < CASES.length * 3) {` to that?

Comment: Still, already after minimal scrolling, the array contains over 4000 entries

Comment: I suggest `cases = [...CASES,...CASES,...CASES]` to be more "controlled" way yeah

Comment: This insert CASES three times to the array, how can I add more on scroll, so that the user will never reach an end on scrolling?

Comment: I achieved it by adding a HostListener which pushes the array every time the user scrolled to the bottom of the page, but since this was a further problem - I'll approve your answer.